# A sum of numpy elements with a given index

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

This code implements a single variable regression without an intercept. It works, but I can't figure out a way to do it without resorting to using slow python iteration.  Any ideas?

```
# y: numpy array of n values, for large n
# coeff: numpy array of n values, for large n
# L : size of result
# l_indices : numpy array of indices from 0 to L-1

def simple_regression(y, coeff, L, l_index):
    numerator = y*coeff
    denominator = np.square(coeff)
    numsum = np.zeros(L)
    denomsum = np.zeros(L)
    for (n,d,l) in zip(numerator,denominator,l_index):
        numsum[l] += n
        denomsum[l] += d
    return numsum / denomsum
```

fundamentally an operation like the following, that doesn't do a bunch of memory allocation:

```
 numsum[l] = np.sum(numerator[l_index == l])
```

(Doing it that way is much lower then my first code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy.bincount`:

```
import numpy as np

def simple_regression(y, coeff, L, l_index):
    numerator = y*coeff
    denominator = np.square(coeff)
    numsum = np.zeros(L)
    denomsum = np.zeros(L)
    for (n,d,l) in zip(numerator,denominator,l_index):
        numsum[l] += n
        denomsum[l] += d
    return numsum / denomsum

def simple_regression_pp(y, coeff, L, l_index):
    numerator = y*coeff
    denominator = np.square(coeff)
    numsum = np.bincount(l_index, numerator, L)
    denomsum = np.bincount(l_index, denominator, L)
    return numsum / denomsum

def simple_regression_br(y, coeff, L, l_index):
    numerator = y*coeff
    denominator = np.square(coeff)
    numsum = np.zeros(L)
    denomsum = np.zeros(L)
    np.add.at(numsum, l_index, numerator)
    np.add.at(denomsum, l_index, denominator)
    return numsum / denomsum

L, N = 1_000, 1_000_000
y, coeff = np.random.random((2, N))
l_index = np.random.randint(0, L, (N,))

from timeit import timeit

print('OP', timeit("simple_regression(y, coeff, L, l_index)", globals=globals(),
                   number=10), 'sec')
print('pp', timeit("simple_regression_pp(y, coeff, L, l_index)",
                   globals=globals(), number=10), 'sec')
print('br', timeit("simple_regression_br(y, coeff, L, l_index)",
                   globals=globals(), number=10), 'sec')
```

Sample run:

```
OP 6.602819449035451 sec
pp 0.12009818502701819 sec
br 1.5504542298149318 sec
```

Answer (score 1):

if you know your index `l_index` only has unique values, you can do:

```
numsum[l_index] += numerator
denomsum[l_index] += denominator
```

if your index is not known to be unique you can do the same thing using `numpy.add.at`:

```
numpy.add.at(numsum, l_index, numerator)
numpy.add.at(denomsum, l_index, denominator)
```